# Prototype Js How to reset frequency in Periodical Updater

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I have read the documentation of Prototype js related to Ajax Periodical Updater and made a lot of search But i still can't figure out how to reset Periodical Updater's Frequency after it reaches a predefined number.

For example suppose i want my page to take info every 10 seconds (frequency) and if it is not able to get any new results it should decay 2 (which means the frequency will be 20, 40, 80 ..) .

**Question**

But when it reaches a number superior or above 60 how to reset it to 10 segonds so that it will start again ? I have seen `Ajax.PeriodicalUpdater#start() → undefined` and `Ajax.PeriodicalUpdater#stop() → undefined` but there is no pratical example on how to use it with a condition

This is my original code

```
<script language='javascript'>

function mettreajour_periodique(span_id, url_traitement, nos_parametres, our_frequency, our_decay)
    {



    var ajax = new Ajax.PeriodicalUpdater ({success: span_id}, url_traitement, {method:'get', frequency: our_frequency, decay: our_decay,  parameters: nos_parametres, evalScripts: true});

    if(our_frequency>=20) { alert(our_frequency);  our_frequency=5; }


    }



//Now i will apply my function here

mettreajour_periodique('nombre_nouveaux_messages', 'barre_du_haut_actualise.php', '&membre=our_member', 10, 2);


</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the options of prototypes `Ajax.PeriodicalUpdater` by using the returned object:

```
ajax.frequency = 50;
```

<kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/edxentb0/)**</kbd>
<kbd>**[Source](https://github.com/sstephenson/prototype/blob/d9411e5/src/prototype/ajax/periodical_updater.js#L209)**</kbd>